# Setting CurrentUICulture doesn't change the UI culture

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, cultureinfo

First of all, let me say I'm using the .NET framework 4.0 so I can't use the `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` property.

This being said, here is my code :

```
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Settings.LANGUAGE.Culture
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Settings.LANGUAGE.Culture

' Initialize the components created with the Visual Studio Designer
' This call is required by the designer.
InitializeComponent()
```

The `Settings` class is my own and the `LANGUAGE.Culture` was created with the `Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(...)` method. It works fine at other places (even at other places in the UI).

These are the first calls of the program's entry point and YET my dateTimePickers still show the dates in english (the language is french).

Any idea on how to fix this? Is there another property I need to set somewhere?

** Edit **

I changed the CustomFormat Property of the dateTimePickers to "MMMM dd, yyyy". I guess it may have caused some overriding on the culture settings but the months are still in English. How do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

This arcticle show's why it doesn't work. Sorry for the trouble.

[Why you can't change the dateTimePickers culture](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;889834&x=18&y=19)